# Multiple Java DatagramSocket instances with UDP reuseaddress true

Tags: java, udp

I have a the following two programs:

1. Server:

   ```
   final DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
   datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
   datagramSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(12345));
   System.out.println(datagramSocket.getReuseAddress());   // returns true

   final byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
   final DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
   datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
   System.out.println(new String(buffer));

   datagramSocket.close();
   ```
2. Client:

   ```
   final byte[] data = "Test".getBytes();
   final DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
   final DatagramPacket datagramPacket 
         = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 12345);
   datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
   datagramSocket.close();
   ```

Now I run the server multiple times on the same machine and run the client once. Then **only one** server receive the message, but the other servers do not receive.

Is it possible, that all servers receive the message on the same time?

Is the error in my code or is there an error in my understanding of the UDP reuse?

Comment: Why? What behaviour are you expecting? If you want broadcast, use broadcast. Or multicast.

Comment: this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085162/6287240) indicates that it is not possible:
_Only if you set the SO_REUSEADDR option (SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress in managed code) can sockets share the port on the same IP address, and even then the behavior is non-deterministic (generally, one or the other socket will receive datagrams, but not both)._

Comment: I understand, it is not possible for unicast messages, but only for multicast messages (i tryed it and it works). thanks a lot

Comment: the right answer is in the comments